# Extend floating div to 100% width of parent container

Tags: css, html, width, css-float

I have a div container that contains a comment. It is set to float left and the avatar container is next to it (which also floats to the left).
Here is a screenshot.

[image]

The css of the white comment container:

```
.comment_content{
    float: left;
/*
    width: 86%;
*/
    margin-left:5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background: url(http://video.chubbyparade.com/img/arrow_left.png) no-repeat 0 8px;
}
```

I want to set this container to fill 100% of the remaining space in the parent container.

If I set it to width:100%, I get a line break (because it now fills 100% of the parent container's width).

How can I set the comment container to fill the remaining space? I used to do this by setting it to width:86%. But that does not look nice if I resize the window (the layout is NOT fixed width).

A table would be the easy way out. But isn't there a solution with css?

Comment: I'm amazed at how people bend over backwards to avoid using a table to present tabular data.

Comment: You can achieve table-like behavior without using tables by using the CSS display property. Namely, display: table table-row and table-cell

Comment: I would also suggest to use a table here. Imagine your comment have a lot of lines: you will run into another problem "under" the image if the `comment_content` floats to the left and it is higher than the image.

Answer (score 3):

Why not instead of floating the comment box, just give a margin-left high enough to clear the avatar image. e.g. if the avatars are 150px wide, give the comment box `margin-left: 155px;` as the comment box is a div (block element) it will naturally fill the rest of the remaining space of the parent div.

**jsfiddle example here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/UHksQ/

**Styling:**

```
.avatar {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}
.comment {
    margin-left:155px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Dave Haigh's solution is a reasonable approach.  If you really, *really* insist on using floats, you can pad the left side of your container out to the width of your portraits, and then give the portraits a margin-left of 100%.  It is kind of silly, but it will work.

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Malkyne/FZcPq/